# Point at a distance 'd' from a given point on a given line in 3D.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a line $l$ and a point $P$ on this line, I need to find any point (say $Q$) in the space that is at a distance $d$ from $P$ such that line segment $PQ$ is perpendicular to $l$. There can be many such points. I just need to find any one. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the vector $m=(a,b,c)$ start at $P$ and point along line $l.$ Assume $a,b$ not both zero (else make a different choice). Then the vector $n=(b,-a,0)$ is normal to $m$. Proceed to divide it by its length, multiply it by $r,$ and add it to $P.$

Added note: If $a=b=0,$ then line $l$ is vertical and one can just add say $(r,0,0)$ to $P.$

Comment: ... but one has to consider apart the case $a=b=0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Note $a,b,c$ cannot *all* be zero. That's what I meant by "else make another choice". If $a=b=0$ [so $c \neq 0,$] use $n=(c.0.-a).$

Comment: I recognize it was not a very interesting remark...

Comment: @JeanMarie Still a good thing to emphasize... I couldn't think of a "universal" method for the problem since even specifying the line direction is a point on the sphere, i.e. a unit vector, and there isn't a unique normal to such a unit vector.

Comment: Rather than dealing with a single special case, I usually present the choice as follows: For nonzero $m$, at least two of $(0,c,-b)$, $(-c,0,a)$ and $(b,-a,0)$ are also nonzero; pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Take any point $R$ not on $l$, and let $u=\vec{PR}$.

Take any point $S$ on $l$, other than $P$, and let $v=\vec{PS}$.

Let $p=\text{proj}_v(u)$ be the vector projection of $u$ on $v$, and let $q=\text{orth}_v(u)=u-p$.

Then $q$ is orthogonal to $v$.

Let $\hat{q}$ be the unit vector in the direction of $q$, and let $Q=P+d\hat{q}$.

It follows that the line segment $PQ$ has length $d$, and is perpendicular to $l$.

**Note:**$\;$This method works in any dimension $2$ or more.